# Remove sibling DIV then get text of parent element

Tags: jquery

This should be simple I'm sure but I keep getting it wrong.

The markup I have is as follows:

```
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="students" value="12345" />
    &nbsp;
    Student Name
    <div>
        [F:0|I:0]
    </div>
</li>
```

When a user clicks on the checkbox, I'd like to take some of the information from the `LI` and create a new, reformatted `LI` to append elsewhere.

```
$('input[name=students]').click(function() {
    var $ele = $(this).parent('li'); // there's my parent LI
    $ele.remove('div'); // get rid of the div within this LI
    var text = $ele.text(); // display the remaining text

    alert(text); // all the text, including the text from the div???
});
```

As you can see by the last line, I get *all* of the text (including the [F:0|I:0] etc, which I don't want). What am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/nen7a/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be

```
$ele.children('div').remove();
```

The [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) removes the set of matched element from dom. You need to call the `.remove()` method on the set of elements which has to be removed - in this case the `div` element

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/353Ru/)

Answer (score 1):

You should specify what you want to remove, remove does not take parameters like

```
.remove(something)
```

rather, its a method on elements like so

```
element.remove()
```

so you have to specify what element you want to remove

```
$ele.find('div').remove('div');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nen7a/1/